# mat-table not getting reset after clearing search filter

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have created a mat-table with mat expansion, So technically the table is nested table. For this nested table I have created a search filter, where user searches anything and if the data is matched to any item in the nested table, then the parent will expand and will show the searched data. In my code I'm able to achieve the functionality which I was looking for. But when i'm clearing the data in search input, the table is not being reset.

For example in the stackblitz code, open the third row, you will notice that there are two nested item. Now search Ohio in the search filter, the row is expanding and showing the data containing ohio. After clearing the search and if you open the third row now, you will notice that there is only one item instead of two. Here the table is not being reset after clearing then search input.
Expected output is the table should resent on clearing of search input.

Below is the code for my toggleRow and search filter

```
  toggleRow(element: User) {
    if (element.addresses && Array.isArray(element.addresses)) {
      const addresses = element.addresses as Address[];
      const filteredAddresses = addresses.filter(address => {
        return address.street.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchFilter.toLowerCase()) ||
          address.zipCode.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchFilter.toLowerCase()) ||
          address.city.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchFilter.toLowerCase());
      });
      element.addresses = new MatTableDataSource(filteredAddresses);
    }
    this.expandedElement = this.expandedElement === element ? null : element;
    this.cd.detectChanges();
    this.innerTables.forEach((table, index) => (table.dataSource as MatTableDataSource<Address>).sort = this.innerSort.toArray()[index]);
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
    if (!filterValue) {
      // Reset data source with original value
      this.dataSource.filter = '';
      this.dataSource.data = this.usersData;
     
      this.expandedElement = null;
    } else {
      // Filter data source based on filter value
      this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data: User, filter: string) => {
        if (!data.addresses) {
          return data.name.toLowerCase().includes(filter) ||
            data.email.toLowerCase().includes(filter) ||
            data.phone.toLowerCase().includes(filter);
        } else {
          const addresses = (data.addresses as MatTableDataSource<Address>).data;
          const matchingAddresses = addresses.filter(a => a.street.toLowerCase() === filter ||
            a.zipCode.toLowerCase() === filter ||
            a.city.toLowerCase() === filter);
          if (matchingAddresses.length > 0) {
            data.addresses = new MatTableDataSource(matchingAddresses);
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        }
      };
      this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
      this.expandedElement = this.dataSource.filteredData[0];
    }
  }
```

Here is the working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-mat-table-zcadjb?file=app/table-expandable-rows-example.ts) for the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check your inner table content and reset the values. Here is the working solution for your problem [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-mat-table-iarvyg?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.ts,app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.css,app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.html)

you need to modify your code below way

```
  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
    if (!filterValue) {
      // Reset data source with original value
      this.dataSource.filter = '';
      this.dataSource.data.forEach(user => {
        if (user.defaultAddress) {
          user.addresses = new MatTableDataSource(user.defaultAddress);
        }
      });
      this.expandedElement = null; // Reset expanded element to null
    } else {
      // Filter data source based on filter value
      this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data: User, filter: string) => {
       console.log(filter,'filter');
        if (!data.addresses) {
          return data.name.toLowerCase().includes(filter) ||
            data.email.toLowerCase().includes(filter) ||
            data.phone.toLowerCase().includes(filter);
        } else {
          const addresses = (data.addresses as MatTableDataSource<Address>).data;
          const matchingAddresses = addresses.filter(a => a.street.toLowerCase() == filter ||
          a.city.toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase()) ||
            a.city.toLowerCase() === filter);
          if (matchingAddresses.length > 0) {
            data.addresses = new MatTableDataSource(matchingAddresses);
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        }
      };
      this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
      const filteredData = this.dataSource.filteredData;
      this.expandedElement = filteredData.length ? filteredData[0] : null;
    }
  }
```